# Convert date to Date Function

Tags: excel

I want to convert a date in a cell to the date function so it is a formula. How do I get the date (using VBA), any date, say, 13 Jun 2020 to =DATE(2020, 6, 13) using variables for the year, month, and day. My code I have tried but won't work. The activecell shows 13-Jun-2020 as a date but appears in the function box as 13/06/2020

```
Sub ConvertDateToDateFunction()
    Dim mvDay, mvMth, mvYr As Integer
    mvDay = Left(ActiveCell, 2)
    mvMth = Mid(ActiveCell, 4, 2)
    mvYr = Right(ActiveCell, 4)
    ActiveCell.Value = "=DATE(mvYr, mvMth, mvDay)"
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to apply an actual [`Range.NumberFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) too?

Comment: I don't understand your question: Excel shows it as a date, and yet you want to convert is as a date (while it is already one). What's your final goal?

Comment: Worksheets are formatted by macro, so that all inputs are blue font and unprotected. Some dates need to be converted to a formula so that they are not made an input and can't be changed by the user once the worksheet is protected, e.g. a date for tax law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your macro won't work because the date is a "real date" and not a string.

Try the following to convert the contents of cells containing a real date to a formula which will return the same date:

```
Option Explicit
Sub dtToFormula()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim vDateParts(2)
    
Set R = [a1:a10]
'Set R = ActiveCell 'or Selection whatever range you want to convert
For Each C In R
    If IsDate(C) And Not C.HasFormula Then
        vDateParts(0) = Year(C.Value2)
        vDateParts(1) = Month(C.Value2)
        vDateParts(2) = Day(C.Value2)
        C.Formula = "=DATE(" & Join(vDateParts, ",") & ")"
    End If
Next C
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. Here is the solution to the smaller one. The code below would do what you intend. It would convert a **text string** in the ActiveCell to a function of similar value and insert it in the cell below the ActiveCell.

```
Sub ConvertDateToDateFunction()

    ' if you don't say what it's supposed to be it'll be a Variant
    Dim mvDay As String, mvMth As String, mvYr As String
    
    mvDay = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 2)
    mvMth = Mid(ActiveCell.Value, 4, 2)
    mvYr = Right(ActiveCell.Value, 4)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Formula = "=DATE(" & mvYr & "," & mvMth & "," & mvDay & ")"
End Sub
```

It's not entirely easy to insert a date as a text string in Excel because Excel will try to recognize a date for a date. Observe that any part of a string is a string, not an integer.

Now about your much bigger problem which is that you don't understand how Excel handles dates. It is such a big problem because you are trying to create a date in Excel in various ways and you run into all sorts of trouble. Read up on the subject [here](http://cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm).

To give you a taste of what you will learn: what you see displayed in a cell isn't what the cell contains. There might be a formula in it and you see a number. And there might be a date and you see a string. What you see is determined by the cell's format. I think Chip Pearson's article will cover that topic. If you need to know more, look for "Cell formatting" on the web.